# Environnement problems with two laravel project on same server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I had a mistake and I would like to know why it appeared.
I have two laravel projects on the same Apache2 ubuntu server. Both projects have two different mysql databases that can be used with phpmyadmin.

When I created my second laravel project (very distinct), I initialized all my environment variables correctly (it worked well).
But on my first project, the "login" route returned an error saying that the "auth.login" view did not exist and debugged the session environment variables of my second project (connection information, etc...)

Do you know how this is possible?

Comment: Are you running both project on the same port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on Apache2. And there are two solutions.

First and the best solution is migrating to Nginx instead of Apache.
But if it's not suitable for you, you can use different environment variable names in your two projects

Comment: Thanks it's the solution